# Does MySQL keep record of row creation date?

Tags: mysql

The question is in the title and to try to make things clearer, I want to add that I know perfectly well how-to record a timestamp for row creation (for creation date or last modification) but my question is really about an internal mechanism that would record this kind of data ...

To explain more, I am currently improving an internally developed CRM and I am adding creation date and last modification date for stored contacts but I have to make-do with 15 years of existing data, so I was wondering if there was a way to retrieve when existing records were created ... (all this to improve our GDPR compliance).

Comment: If there were a way, you would not even need what you added for current data. I dont know of a way.

Comment: No, it does not. That would add 8 bytes per row.